# Timeout exception is showing after button click

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, timeout, timeoutexception

After button click page get refresh and redirect to another page.In my case after button click i gave timeout for page refresh but after button click it showing timeout exception without time wait .i used all type of time wait event i used thread.sleep() but no use.

---

Exception :

> FAILED: createEventTest
>   org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for page load.
>   Command duration or timeout: 15.08 seconds
>   Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b1534ae328c771e0856c93e187490ca824', time: '2016-03-15 10:43:46'
>   System info: host: 'pc', ip: '192.168.1.6', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.7.0_79'
>   Session ID: a29803a6-5ec1-4791-b26f-3ab0adb47c7b
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
>   Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=46.0.1}]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:327)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:85)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:51)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6.click(Unknown Source)
>       at com.pv.pages.CreateEventPage.createApprovedEvent(CreateEventPage.java:356)
>       at com.pv.pages.CreateEventPage.createEvent(CreateEventPage.java:688)
>       at com.pv.tests.CreateEventTests.createEventTest(CreateEventTests.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
>       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:643)
>       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:820)
>       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1128)
>       at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
>       at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
>       at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782)
>       at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
>       at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1246)
>       at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1171)
>       at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1066)
>       at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:113)
>       at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:206)
>       at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:177)
>   Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for page load.
>   Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b1534ae328c771e0856c93e187490ca824', time: '2016-03-15 10:43:46'
>   System info: host: 'pc', ip: '192.168.1.6', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.7.0_79'
>   Driver info: driver.version: unknown
>       at .Utils.installClickListener/e<(file:///C:/Users/fu/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous7103862578695056607webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:9372)
>       at .WebLoadingListener/e(file:///C:/Users/fu/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous7103862578695056607webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:5142)
>       at .WebLoadingListener/<(file:///C:/Users/fu/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous7103862578695056607webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:5150)
>       at .fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify(file:///C:/Users/fu/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous7103862578695056607webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:625)

Comment: Share your Selenium code also.

Comment: Code:
//Clicking button
createEvent_btn.click();
//I used explicit and Implicit time wait even i used thread.sleep()
but no use.
lib.implicitWait(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

Comment: @Gobi Your question lacks code, `formatting` and methods already used, I think. Please refer to StackOverflow guidelines for formatting. As to question itself, have you tried `waitFor(ExpectedCondition<T>)`?

Answer (score 0):

Tried this?

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to javascript for page load .Now my code running fine.

```
public static void waitForPageToLoad() {

do {

js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

pageLoadStatus = (String)js.executeScript("return document.readyState");

System.out.print(".");

} while ( !pageLoadStatus.equals("complete") );

System.out.println();

System.out.println("Page Loaded.");

}
```